# What is the most up-to-date recommended seed/setup for latest riot version (3.11)?

Tags: riot.js

What is the most elegant way to get a riot based UI today?

i'd love the following points to be addressed:

1. A proper code-mapping for easy debugging
2. A good way to bundle the application (so far i used Webpack and JSPM)
3. It would be lovely if it would work elegantly with Typescript.
4. Is it best to use Tag files, or straight JS? If the later, would it be better to use a class that inherit from riot's tag class? If so, can i place the template code in a different file?
5. Future compatibility: i saw that there's going to be a change (that "export default" thing) - how would you recommend to write the code for the smoothest migration path?

If you have more items for consideration - please add them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking these questions. I have tried to answer to all your questions hoping they could be useful also to other Riot.js users

> A proper code-mapping for easy debugging

the riot compiler generates simply javascript code without modifying too much the structure of your original source code. Any modern browser should be able to provide with `debugger` breakpoints and `console` calls all the debugging tools you need. Check for example the stack [trace of this error](https://plnkr.co/edit/l3biNmBB0i59fJ09BjdF?p=preview) you don't need much more to figure out where it's coming from.

> A good way to bundle the application (so far i used Webpack and JSPM)

In this repo we provide 3 different javascript bundle examples: [rollup](https://github.com/riot/examples/tree/gh-pages/rollup), [webpack](https://github.com/riot/examples/tree/gh-pages/webpack), [riot-compiler](https://github.com/riot/examples/tree/gh-pages/todo-app-precompiled). I personally prefer rollup but you can (and should) use whatever works best for you and your team.

> It would be lovely if it would work elegantly with Typescript.

The riot public methods are already available as Typescript interfaces: 
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/riot
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/riot-route

I am not a typescript user and that's why I will not invest time in making examples in a technology I don't use but PR are welcome

> Is it best to use Tag files, or straight JS? If the later, would it be better to use a class that inherit from riot's tag class? If so, can i place the template code in a different file?

I recommend you to just use Tag files because riot was designed as component library and it embraces completely the philosophy of components composition vs class inheritance. If you have code you share across several components you can either use mixins or import it with your bundler directly in your tags [see for example](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/nisiu/blob/b48f21f9dcffa7b77844d69eba9e65e13f0d256d/src/components/modal.tag#L8-L11)

> Future compatibility: i saw that there's going to be a change (that "export default" thing) - how would you recommend to write the code for the smoothest migration path?

Riot 3 will be not compatible with Riot 4. (that will be a full rewrite) I can't recommend any best practice to make your code portable to Riot 4. Remember that Riot 3 will be still supported and your code will run even on IE9 for the next 10 years. Once riot 4 will be released and the API will be stable I can provide more hints about a migration path.

Comment: Why is Babel used in all the existing examples?